# Mount a folder running a docker-in-docker container in a custom GitHub action

Tags: docker, github-actions, mount

I run a docker-in-docker container in my GitHub action and need to mount a folder from the host (repository).

**action.yml**

```
...
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
...
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM docker:stable
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
...
docker run -d ... -v /github/workspace/.github/config:/opt/dest/config ...
...
```

The files in the folder do exist under the *GITHUB_WORKSPACE* from a debug print in the *entrypoint.sh*. But they appear not to be mounted properly to the inner container.

Comment: Please see this if it helps - https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

The socket solution should probably solve your problem. You may also want to look at -- -privileged flag. More details about this can be found here - https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/

Comment: Tried mounting the socket and the privileged flag. That didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

When using the official [docker dind setup](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker), there are two components to it: one container with the Docker CLI (`docker:latest`) and another container with the Docker Daemon (`docker:dind`). The Docker-in-Docker containers are created inside the latter container (`docker:dind`), so that's the one to on which you should setup the host mounts. I suspect you may be setting up the mounts into the Docker CLI container instead.

Another piece of advice: the default Docker-in-Docker setup relies on unprivileged containers or a socket connection to the host's Docker; both provide weak isolation and can mess up your host setup. To get proper isolation, look into [Sysbox](https://github.com/nestybox/sysbox), a new runc that will enable you to run Docker-in-Docker (and more) much more cleanly.